# with statement needed if you read a whole file at once?

Tags: python, with-statement

I use this since 12 years:

```
content=open(foo).read()
```

New colleagues coming from university say: You should use the `with` statement.

```
with open(foo) as fd:
    content=fd.read()
```

I don't see a good reason why I should type more than necessary.

The only benefit the `with` statement gives me: The `fd` gets closed as soon as the block gets left. Without the `with` statement the `fd` gets closed if the garbage collector starts to do his job.

Please tell me: Why should I use the `with` statement if I read a whole file at once?

**Update**: I know how the with statement works, I know that it is useful (e.g. writing to a file).

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm is a useful explanation of what it does.

Comment: @duffymo "*and now requires it*" - that's a blatantly false assertion...

Comment: Note that details of garbage collection are different on different python implementations.  Are you only using CPython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That you read the whole file at once has no impact on when the file is closed. No matter what you do with the file (short of explicitly closing it), without `with` the file remains open until its `__del__` method is called. So the reason for using `with` apply just as much to your use case as to every other case of file I/O:

It *definitely* closes the file as early as possible. It's immune to reference cycles and it's more portable to other Python implementations (imagine the anger when you could get a 5x performance increase from PyPy but can't use it because your program crashes from having too many files open!). Even if it doesn't matter for the *current* context, code gets moved around and requirements change. It's an easy way (just one extra line!) to future proof code.

If it's a one-off script that will only open two files per run, it's still good style and a good habit. Same reason you don't change indentation to *five* spaces in one-off scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Well for your purposes, there is no real reason. However, `with`s usefulness is not limited to files alone. It can be used with threads. For example:

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
    # Critical section
    statements
    # End critical section
```

The `with` statement automatically acquires and releases a lock when control enters and leaves the block of statements that follows.

Its become good practice to use it since it adds additional safety to your code, and makes file reading sections more prominent and readable (in my opinion), because when you use a `with` statement, you are essentially inside an indentation block.

Comment: worth noting that in your example is the `lock` object that implements the logic you mentioned. The `with` keyword only triggers it.

Comment: I don't think this is a convincing argument. OP asks why `with` should be used in *this* example, not what it's good for in general. As an analogy: The `+` operator is useful for accumulating numbers, but that doesn't mean it should be used for accumulating strings.

Comment: @guettli exactly, and in truth for your purposes, nothing much. That is pretty much what everyone is saying. Its just best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a good practice to close unused handles instead of waiting for GC.

By the way your point is true, no notable benefits using `with` in your context.
And probably less than a millisecond of penalty due to the explicit closing using `with`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is obvious: The context manager closes for example an open file after leaving the context manager block. Using context managers give you extra security.

For example I had this code:

```
content = open('foo.txt').read()
os.unlink('foo.txt')
```

This code worked perfectly on Linux but failed on Windows since the file remained open and Windows caused an exception (file locked or something like that as far as I recall).

This error would not be possible with writing the code as

```
with open('foo.txt') as fp:
    content= fp.read()
os.unlink('foo.txt')
```

The file would be closed after reading the content and before trying to unlink() the file.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. OP asks why using `with` in its example would be better than the one-liner.

Comment: This is a good reason. Here the one liner would not work on windows. I never use windows, but nevertheless, that's a good point.

Answer (score -3):

The with statement is better because it will ensure you always close the file, even if an exception is raised.

Comment: this does not answer the question.